# How to store a datetime in round trip format in the .NET Application Settings system

Tags: .net, datetime, application-settings

So tonight I asked a question about storing date time formats in the [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) system of .NET.  The answer I got makes sense but got me thinking about another situation.

This is only hypothetical, I may not find myself in need of using this but it would be interesting to know what the common answer is.

It seems the Settings system converts a datetime into the "The General Date Long Time ("G")" format (see [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) on MSDN) which is fine if that is all you want but what if you want to store a value using the "The Round-trip ("O", "o")" format?

As far as I can see at the moment you would need to store that as a string and parse it yourself.  Is that the only way when using the designer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fastest and most efficient way of losslessly serializing a `DateTime` is using the [ToBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary.aspx) and [FromBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.frombinary.aspx) methods.

```
settings.Timestamp = date.ToBinary();
// ...
DateTime date = DateTime.FromBinary(settings.Timestamp);
```

Comment: That will probably be the best option in most cases.  It's just less human readable in an XML output.  One day I might do a quick benchmark to see what difference it really makes using this vs a string formatted value.  But for now this will be fine, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I have amended the answer with a solution that works.